# Testing GCP Cloud Function trigger with PubSub testcontainer

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, testcontainers, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

Is there any way to do integration tests for the Cloud Function using `PubSubEmulatorContainer`?

My Cloud Function is triggered by the message in the PubSub topic as follows

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageIngest implements Consumer<PubSubMessage> {

    private final MessageResource msgResource;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @Override
    public void accept(PubSubMessage pubSubMessage) {
        var message = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubSubMessage.getData()), UTF_8);
        msgResource.ingest(objectMapper.readValue(message, Message.class));
    }
}
```

So far what I found about using `PubSubEmulatorContainer` for the integration testing is to publish there or subscribe from nothing about how to listen to the topic and trigger the test on publishing to the topic. My assumption is that I need to do that within the `contextLoads()` test.

For the live code trigger is provided during the deployment as an argument

```
gcloud functions deploy myCloudFunction --trigger-topic=$TOPIC_TO_LISTEN
```

PS.
Provided example from the comments fails for me on testconainers version 1.18.0

`testSend()` errors out as

```
[ault-executor-0] c.g.c.s.p.c.p.PubSubPublisherTemplate    : Publishing to test-topic topic failed.
com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Topic not found
com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Subscription does not exist
```

and `testWorker()` as

```
[ault-executor-0] c.g.c.s.p.c.p.PubSubPublisherTemplate    : Publishing to test-topic topic failed.
com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Topic not found
com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Subscription does not exist (resource=test-subscription)
```

Comment: I think you can, I haven't done it before but can help. Not sure if you are using spring cloud functions or another one but somehow there should be a connection string where you can set the emulator endpoint. Look at this example https://github.com/saturnism/testcontainers-gcloud-examples/blob/main/springboot/pubsub-example/src/test/java/com/example/springboot/pubsub/PubSubIntegrationTests.java#L141

Comment: @EddúMeléndez I saw that example and the problem is that it fails with the current version of PubSub testcontainer

Comment: It fails because of testcontainers or the image itself? Can you update the question with your logs, please?

Comment: @EddúMeléndez I have added errors when it fails

Comment: well, the PubSubEmulatorContainer doesn't provide a topic, so, this should be manually created. After that, subscription for that topic should be created too. Then you should submit the message

Comment: @EddúMeléndez so the GitHub example is incomplete?

Comment: The github example does everything through code. What you want to do is different and I want to do that too but also have some issues with it due to the message is received but null

Comment: @EddúMeléndez Interesting because when I try to run the GitHub example it throws the same errors for me as I will use it with my code so not sure if the testcontainers changed anything since that code was released.

Comment: To be clear, the error I talked about is receiving the message from pubsub but a null message when arriving to the function. However, your error is related to missing topic/subscription which you actually need to send the message and be processed by the function.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez Based on the GitHub example, in my case, it should be done in the `setup()` method lines #102 and #103

Comment: I'm just trying to help with the shared information but I think I can not continue due to lack of context. I just can say it can be an initialization issue, I do not have that issue but can not say what is missing in you case unless you can share a repository to take a look.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez Yeah I know you are trying to help and I'm happy about that. I'm just trying to point out that the GitHub example doesn't even work. I have copied that test example with the necessary dependencies and then run `testSend()` - it will fail on line #128  as `PubSubIntegrationTests.testSend() throws java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException,java.lang.InterruptedException` because `test-subscription` doesn't exist. My point is that example may be obsolete to what testcontainers repo offers now for SpringBoot

Comment: Oh, ok. my fault so the example is not working. I know those are not updates. Can you check on this repo https://github.com/ddobrin/testcontainers-gcloud-examples ?

Comment: @EddúMeléndez Not sure what is different but that one example works for me. Now can take a look further. Thanks!

Comment: @EddúMeléndez it came up that test will work fine with the service implementation which uses `PubSubPublisherTemplate` but not for `Publisher`. Will error out that resource for the topic not found.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez I have an open new SO question regarding that issue above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318081/testing-gcp-pubsub-with-testcontainer-pubsub-emulator but at least I got my function triggered by that PubSub test mentioned in that new post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do integration tests for the Cloud Function using PubSubEmulatorContainer. You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-pubsub-integration-test#functions_pubsub_integration_test-java).